# Python добавить ключи для запуска

Tags: python

Есть скрипт python, мне нужно запускать его с ключем.

Пример: `python script.py --path путь`

Как в коде отслеживать то, что пользователь ввел?

Comment: Используйте лог. Либо, используйте debug в какой-нибудь IDE

Comment: @hedgehogues Можно поподробнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте пакет [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). С его помощью Вы можете добавлять флаги, с которыми следует запускать Ваше приложение.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example of a single flag acting as a boolean and an option.")
parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', const="bar", default=False)
parser.add_argument('--woo')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.foo:
  print(args.foo)
else:
  print("Using the default, boolean False.")

if args.woo:
  print(args.woo)
else:
  print("Using the default, boolean False.")
```

Comment: А как вывести ошибку, если нет аргументов?

Comment: Используйте try

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `sys.argv`
Вам нужно сначала сделать импорт библиотеки `sys`, а потом обращаться к нужному элементу массива `sys.argv`

Вот пример:

```
import sys

if '--path' in sys.argv:
    print sys.argv[sys.argv.index('--path') + 1]
```

Comment: Для чего использовать `sys`, когда есть готовый пакет, производящий более или менее удобный парсинг аргументов?